# How to Import a Material File (.mat) into LibGDX and add it to a mesh?

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, libgdx

In Unity3D, I have fbx (for mesh) file and .mat file (for material) to visualize a human hand.

In LibGDX, I managed to import the fbx file but cannot figure out how to import the .mat file and assign it to the mesh. So currently the imported model is just a white hand.

Comment: You want to take the material from the unity and move in LibGDX?

Comment: @V.Borodinov: Yes.

Comment: But .mat internal unity format

Comment: @V.Borodinov Is there any way to export it or embed it into fbx file that contains the mesh?

Answer (score 1):

The .mat file is Unity's internal file format so it can't be used directly.

[Unity FBX Exporter](https://github.com/KellanHiggins/UnityFBXExporter) allows you to export your model and material to FBX, albeit with some limitations. This is the only way I have found so far to export material from Unity.